# Gridview and LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which contains a linkbutton in its templatefield. What I want to know is, when I click on the linkbutton, how can I get the text of the linkbutton into a string called 'name'?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

Provide event handler for Click event:

```
<asp:GridView id="myGrid" runat="server">
<columns>
   <asp:templatefield>
      <itemtemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton id="MyButton" 
           Text="SuperText" 
           OnClick="MyButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
      </itemtemplate>
   </asp:templatefield>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In event handler use the following code:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
       if(btn != null)
          string name = btn.Text; // SuperText

    }
```

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it is what you looking for - so other people will be able to see it. :)